# Calling COM module from node.js

Tags: node.js, azure, com, npm

We have a closed COM engine we need to call from our node.js server.
Is there a package I can use to call this engine from node.js?

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to build your own C++ extension to node.js.

This extension can use your COM component. However It looks complicated and time consuming to build an extension for node.js.

Check here fro more info http://nodejs.org/api/addons.html

Comment: ya, I know I can do it, but I expected someone would develop some bridge.